# Ember.js: converting an app to Router API V2

Tags: ember.js

I'm pretty new to Ember.js and while developing an app I just found out about the new router API. which was merged and has no documentation at all (except for this - https://gist.github.com/3981133)

I have no idea about how to even start converting my app to the new router API.
this "walkthrough" doesn't help much.

1) how do I connect templates to named outlets, for example {{outlet main}} ?

2) I use App.router.someController and App.router.get('store').findAll() and .find() all over, what should those be replaced with ?

3) is there any change to the handlebars tag in html `<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="templateName">` ?

that all I can think for now..

Comment: I found this pretty informative: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ed_o3_59ME

Comment: I also did an introduction to ember.js and the new router screencast for anyone who might be trying to learn the new api http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/01/03/Intro-to-ember-js-and-the-new-router-api/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just finished this upgrade myself on a small example project

https://github.com/toranb/ember-code-camp

To answer a few of your questions directly

1) no more connectOutlets noise - just map a route to an ember route class/object. this approach is very convention based btw (template/view/controller/route all match)

```
CodeCamp.Router.map(function(match) {
  match("/").to("sessions");
  match("/session/:session_id").to("session"); //no route needed -ember will apply the context for you
  match("/speaker/:speaker_id").to("speaker"); //same as above so long as my handlebars template name matches (speaker for this route)
});

CodeCamp.SessionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupControllers: function(controller) {
    controller.set('content', CodeCamp.Session.find());
  }
});
```

2 a) you get the store in the router like so

```
App.YourObject.find()
```

2 b) you can commit the store from within your controller like so

```
this.get('store').commit()
```

3) my handlebars stuff was unchanged with the exception of route related helpers

```
I remove action helpers defined with <a {{action and used linkTo instead

  {{#linkTo 'session' session}}View Session Details{{/linkTo}}
```

Comment: regarding 1), how do you setup multiple controllers in a route ? (for example, I want to set something in a NavigationController which is connected to {{outlet navigation}}

Comment: good question -From what I can tell, the convention is that you only have 1 controller per route but then again the docs are really lacking at this time. If I stumble across some docs on this in the future I'll update this answer.

Comment: to setup multiple controllers in a route: set properties from setupControllers() callback, then connect outlets from the renderTemplates callback. So for example, in setupControllers() you'd do controllerFor('navigation').set('a', 'b') and in renderTemplates() call render('navigation', {controller: 'navigation', outlet: 'navigation})